# Creating table from distance raster

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, distance, zonal-statistics, statistics

I have made a distance raster in ArcMap using the Euclidean Distance tool from one town to another that appears to be OK (see attached image). I'm trying to determine the distance from each parcel in one town to the corresponding parcel in the other town. I need to create a table with the value of the mean distance from the old town to the new town using zonal statistics as a table tool. I have tried using both the new and old layers as input raster and used the distance raster as my input value raster. The function runs but returns an empty table (see 2nd pic). Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: You left out the (very necessary) graphics. Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: Your forgot the screenshot in hit question.